# ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx' while debuging project with ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gdb

Trying to debug project that uses ncurses from Eclipse IDE. Got error:

```
fff@ubuntu:~/workspace/ttt/Debug$ GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
Error opening terminal: unknown.
Quit
```

Application should start in another terminal. There is [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345873/gdb-crashes-with-importerror-no-module-named-libstdcxx-v6-printers) regarding this problem but I can't find how to fix it anyway.