# GDB: ImportError: No module named libstdcxx.v6.printers

Tags: windows, gdb, mingw-w64, msys2

I have MSYS2 and MinGW64 installed under Windows 7.

gdb reports "ImportError: No module named libstdcxx.v6.printers":

```
$ gdb  
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1  
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>  
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"  
and "show warranty" for details.  
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-msys".  
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.  
For bug reporting instructions, please see:  
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.  
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:  
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.  
For help, type "help".  
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>  
ImportError: No module named libstdcxx.v6.printers  
/etc/gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:  
Error while executing Python code.  
(gdb) quit
```

I have found several links:

[Import Error: No module name libstdcxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389977/import-error-no-module-name-libstdcxx)

[ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx' while debuging project with ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375423/importerror-no-module-named-libstdcxx-while-debuging-project-with-ncurses)

[How to enable gdb pretty printing for C++ STL objects in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/how-to-enable-gdb-pretty-printing-for-c-stl-objects-in-eclipse-cdt)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/345873/gdb-crashes-with-importerror-no-module-named-libstdcxx-v6-printers

https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/383

but none of them helps.

**Update:**

There are 2 gdbinit.

C:\Appl\msys64\etc\gdbinit:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0] + '/../../gcc-6.3.0/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

C:\Appl\msys64\mingw64\etc\gdbinit:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0] + 'C:/Appl/msys64/mingw64/share/gcc-7.1.0/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
end
```

Comment: What is line 6 of `/etc/gdbinit` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I have found 2 of them. See the post updated.

Comment: Do you have a `libstdcxx` directory anywhere under your `C:/Appl/msys64` directory? It ought to be in `<some prefix>/gcc-<version>/python/libstdcxx`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, found: C:\Appl\msys64\mingw64\share\gcc-7.1.0\python\libstdcxx; v6 subdir present and containing printers.py

Comment: Should I write something like `sys.path = 'C:/Appl/msys64/mingw64/share/gcc-7.1.0/python'`?

Comment: Try `sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Appl/msys64/mingw64/share/gcc-7.1.0/python')`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, it helped when I replaced the string in  C:\Appl\msys64\etc\gdbinit. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd like to see what `sys.path[0]` is, because both gdbinit files seem to think it should be some sort of MSYS base directory. Could you show the output of `gdb -nx -batch -ex "python import sys; print(sys.path[0])"`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, /usr/share/gdb/python

Comment: OK. Then `C:\Appl\msys64\etc\gdbinit` probably has the correct contents, except for the GCC version number. If an update changes either that file or the installed version of GCC, you now know how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, thank you once more.

Comment: I wonder why this is happening. This is a clean install ;(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for KonstantinL's answer
I also encountered this problem and solved it

my gcc version is 11.1 ，There is only one gdbinit at etc/gdbinit

And I found the libstdcxx library at /usr/share/gcc-11.3.0/python

Refer to KonstantinL's answer

Modify the gdbinit as “sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc-11.3.0/python')”

GDB can run normally

Thanks for KonstantinL's answer